# Better way to copy text in a textbox to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, synchronization, textchanged

Good day!

I have this problem that every text change in the text box, selected item in the datagriview should copy its value. I have this code but it lags when I type(like very fast) in the textbox.

Is there any better way to do this w/o lagging?

Please help...

Here's what I have so far:

```
private void txtText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView1[2, pos].Value = txtText.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to limit the number of events that are handled. Do your requirements allow you to use the `TextBox` `Validated` or `LostFocus` events instead?

If not you could look into [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) and throttle your `TextChanged` event. This can be achieved like so:

```
IObservable<EventPattern<EventArgs>> observable = Observable.FromEventPattern(
  txtText, "TextChanged").Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
  .Subscribe(ep=> DataGridView1[2, pos].Value = txtText.Text;);
```

You could also throttle with a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Timer.aspx).

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Interval = 500;
myTimer.Tick = OnTimerTick;

private void OnTimerTick(object o, EventArgs e)
{
  myTimer.Stop();
  DataGridView1[2, pos].Value = txtText.Text;
}

private void txtText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!myTimer.Enabled) myTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm not allowed to use Rx or anything... Also, I'm not familiar with Rx and have not enough time to review it. Sad, isn't it? Well, is there any other way to solve my problem aside from Rx?

Comment: @JackFrost, You could make your own throttle with the [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks! Timer is better than setting an event in "OnKeyPress". Well I tried putting it on the "OnKeyPress" event and it was a bit better compared to TextChanged. But now I'm using the timer. Thanks mate!

Comment: @JackFrost, no worries. Looks like you are new to StackOverflow. Be sure to mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Comment: yes, I am and I don't know how to "Mark an answer".. EDITED: I think I figured it out. I just need to click that "Check" under that "Voting" right?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `txtText_KeyPress` event and see if the user pressed `enter` key (key code = 13).

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I need to show the changes "real-time"