# Event when finished selecting items?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have a ListView control that is displaying a list of files in "Details" mode.  I will allow the users to select one or a number of these files at the same time.

I have an action I want to carry out on the selected files, however as it seems logical to me that I only initiate this action once I know what files are selected.

To clarify:

User selects one file - onSelectionFinished is fired and doThisAction(selectedFile[0]) can proceed.

User selects multiple files - onSelectionFinished is fired and doThisAction(selectedFile[0]) can proceed follwed by doThisAction(selectedFile[1]) etc...

I have tried using SelectedIndexChanged but when the user selects eg 3 files, my action routine is fired 6 times:  Index 0, Indices 0, 1 and then Indices 0,1,2 - a very inefficient program!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks.  I was not aware of this convention.  I will be in future! Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you allow the user to select multiple files then you're not going to know when the user is `done` selecting and you certainly don't went to run the operation with every selection change.

Instead of trying to react to selection events you should have a button (or some other control) that runs the operation(s) on the items selected in the list view. Only the user knows when he/she is `done` and will tell you.

Comment: D'oh!  I'm clearly needing my bed!  Thanks for that!  One Button control added and a shuffle of control positions and I'm cooking!  Cheers :-) Accepted as answer

Comment: @tip2tail: Glad to be of help. I've been down those rabbit holes myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could throttle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. If the user has not changed their selection in a certain time period then assume they are done and call your method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17396827/1914530) for an example.

However, it may be better for you to let the user decide when he/she is done as described by @Paul Sasik by means of a button click.

Comment: +! throttling can work but not so well with people. Users are freaking unpredictable and if you try to `think for them` they will burn you!

Answer (score 0):

Dont set the selection event instead let user select items needed and place the listview mouseclick event and check if its the right mousebutton,and inside do the work

```
        private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                //do work here
            }
        }
```

you can add a contextmenu to the listview so when user right-clicks it will add more flexibility(with more options on what to do to that selection):

```
        MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("&Copy");
        MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem("&Delete");
        contextMenu1.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] { menuItem1, menuItem2 });
        listView1.ContextMenu = contextMenu1;
```